# How to forward ports on the same Ubuntu machine? I want my webserver be available on 80 and 8880 port

Tags: apache2, port-forwarding

How do I forward ports on the same Ubuntu machine? I want my webserver be available on 80 and 8880 port.

Or maybe I could making my apache listening not only on 80 port, but also on 8880? Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

Just use the [Listen](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) directive in your Apache configuration file.

For instance, right now you'll probably have `Listen 80`, just add `Listen 8880` after it:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8880
```

and restart Apache.